# Work done by frictional force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, work

I used to assume that work done by friction is dependent of path it follows but i am confused as this question  or answer of this question suggests that it has nothing to do with give theta

So am i wrong or am i missing something? !

[image]

Comment: What exactly was your solution and your doubt? work done by friction force $f$ is $W = -fl$ where $l$ is the length of path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work done on each slope is proportional to the friction force and the distance traveled:

- Friction force is $$F = \mu\, N = \mu\, m g \cos \theta$$
- Distance traveled is $$ \ell= \sqrt{ (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2} = \Delta x \sqrt{1+\tan^2 \theta} = \frac{\Delta x}{\cos \theta} $$
- Combined, the work is $$W = F \ell = \mu\, m g \cos \theta \frac{\Delta x}{\cos \theta} = \mu \, m g \, \Delta x$$

So the slope cancels out for this case. This is a nice problem showing how on special circumstances friction is path independent.